# Recently, all icons from my $HOME directory appear on Desktop

Tags: icons, clutter

I run Xubuntu (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Kernel 5.15.0-82-generic).

From earlier answers, I tried `#XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/` in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` file but it did not work.

Also, `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop`, and creating an empty file Desktop, did not solve the problem. After the restart, there is again `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME`.

Any ideas?

Comment: `mv $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs  $HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs.bak` and `xdg-user-dirs-update` login anew.

Comment: Thanks. I did not change user-dirs.dirs, it seems that some update did it. And I have forgotten that I used a Croatian word for Desktop during instalation.

Comment: Unfortunately, after a few log-ins, the desktop is cluttered again!